# debugging jasmine test cases run by gulp in visual studio code?

Tags: debugging, jasmine, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to debug jasmine test cases in visual studio code debug console.
Below is my launch.json and gulpfile.js configuration :

[image]

In my gulp task I tried using 'gulp-jasmine' to run test cases and "gulp-karma" (*commented below jasmine*) alternatively. Now using either one I can successfully excute my test cases through command line (*gulp "task name"*) or through task.json file in vs code. 
However, I want to debug my jasmine test cases(*spec/StockSpec.js* ) itself. On running debug (f5), the debugger successfully pauses on entry point in gulpfile.js as below :

[image]

From here on I'm not able to navigate to my jasmine test cases no matter which scenario I choose:

**Scenario 1**: On clicking Step Over (F10) --it skips to next gulp task 
**Scenario 2**: On clicking Step In/out (F11 / shift +F11) --it jumps to some internal module.js , index.js etc files.

How should I proceed further?

Comment: I don't know VS, so can't offer a solution, but I can clear some of your confusion. Gulp just runs the Jasmine tests, in the same way it can run other binaries. It doesn't make js calls to your Jasmine specs, so a breakpoint in gulp isn't going to get you very far!

Answer (score 2):

This runs through `gulpfile.js`, but doesn't trigger a gulp task itself. The startup program needs to be `gulp.js` with the gulp task as argument. You can then simply set a breakpoint in your unit test.

The following launch configuration works for me to trigger the `unittests` gulp task:

```json
{
  "name": "Launch",
  "type": "node",
  "request": "launch",
  "program": "${workspaceRoot}/node_modules/gulp/bin/gulp.js",
  "stopOnEntry": false,
  "args": [
    "unittests"
  ],
  "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}/src/",
  "preLaunchTask": null,
  "runtimeExecutable": null,
  "runtimeArgs": [
    "--nolazy"
  ],
  "env": {
    "NODE_ENV": "development"
  },
  "externalConsole": false,
  "sourceMaps": false,
  "outDir": null
}
```

Comment: Thank you for putting me in the right direction. Please note that vs code now seems to have first class support for adding launch configurations of gulp tasks via the UI.